# Azure - HDInsight Hbase Data Insertion Failed

Tags: java, azure, hbase, iot, azure-hdinsight

Currently we are migrating our IoT platform as a PAAS service. We are using HDInsight Hbase for all IoT data insertion. Now i am able to create and delete tables in the HBase from java application. But i am not able insert or select any data from the HDInight Hbase table. Please suggest me if anything is missing in code level.

HBase Insert Java Code:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // define some people
 Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

 // Example of setting zookeeper values for HDInsight
 // in code instead of an hbase-site.xml file
 //
  config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
             "zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181");
 config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
 config.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
 //
 //NOTE: Actual zookeeper host names can be found using Ambari:
 //curl -u admin:PASSWORD -G "https://CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTERNAME/hosts"

 //Linux-based HDInsight clusters use /hbase-unsecure as the znode parent
 config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure");
 System.out.println("1 - " + config);
 String[][] people = {
     { "1", "Marcel", "Haddad", "marcel@fabrikam.com"},
     { "2", "Franklin", "Holtz", "franklin@contoso.com" },
     { "3", "Dwayne", "McKee", "dwayne@fabrikam.com" },
     { "4", "Rae", "Schroeder", "rae@contoso.com" },
     { "5", "Rosalie", "burton", "rosalie@fabrikam.com"},
     { "6", "Gabriela", "Ingram", "gabriela@contoso.com"} };

 HTable table = new HTable(config, "people");
 System.out.println("2 - " + table);
 // Add each person to the table
 //   Use the `name` column family for the name
 //   Use the `contactinfo` column family for the email
 for (int i = 0; i< people.length; i++) {
     Put person = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(people[i][0]));
     person.add(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("first"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][1]));
     person.add(Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes("last"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][2]));
     person.add(Bytes.toBytes("contactinfo"), Bytes.toBytes("email"), Bytes.toBytes(people[i][3]));
     System.out.println("3 - " + person);
     table.put(person);
     System.out.println("4 - " + table);
 }
 // flush commits and close the table
 System.out.println("5 - " + table);
 table.flushCommits();
 table.close();
 System.out.println("6 - " + table);
```

Error :

```
2083 [main] INFO  o.a.h.h.z.RecoverableZooKeeper - Process identifier=hconnection-0x524d6d96 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=zk0-bdtrin.un52sso10ikejkjuhwkxemgbfa.rx.internal.cloudapp.net:2181,zk4-bdtrin.un52sso10ikejkjuhwkxemgbfa.rx.internal.cloudapp.net:2181,zk1-bdtrin.un52sso10ikejkjuhwkxemgbfa.rx.internal.cloudapp.net:2181
7616 [main] WARN  o.a.h.c.Configuration - hbase-site.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: dfs.support.append;  Ignoring.
7616 [main] WARN  o.a.h.h.u.DynamicClassLoader - Failed to identify the fs of dir /hbase/lib, ignored
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasb
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar:?]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:104) [hbase-common-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:238) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:879) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [?:1.8.0_151]
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [?:1.8.0_151]
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [?:1.8.0_151]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:329) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:144) [hbase-client-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
      at com.trinity.iot.storm.topology.HbaseTest.main(HbaseTest.java:34) [classes/:?]
7697 [main] WARN  o.a.h.c.Configuration - hbase-site.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: dfs.support.append;  Ignoring.
7750 [main] INFO  o.a.h.h.z.RecoverableZooKeeper - Process identifier=hconnection-0x2d0399f4 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181
```

hbase-site.xml

```
 <configuration>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
      <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>dfs.support.append</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.bucketcache.combinedcache.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.bucketcache.ioengine</name>
      <value>file:/mnt/hbase/cache.data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.bucketcache.percentage.in.combinedcache</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.bucketcache.size</name>
      <value>81920</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.bulkload.staging.dir</name>
      <value>/apps/hbase/staging</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
      <value>1048576</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
      <value>35</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.SecureBulkLoadEndpoint</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.custom-extensions.root</name>
      <value>/hdp/ext/2.6/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.fs.shutdown.hook.wait</name>
      <value>600000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>
      <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction.jitter</name>
      <value>0.50</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
      <value>10737418240</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier</name>
      <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size</name>
      <value>134217728</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.mslab.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hstore.compaction.max</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hstore.compaction.max.size</name>
      <value>32212254720</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.hstore.compactionThreshold</name>
      <value>3</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
      <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/local</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.distributed.log.splitting</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
      <value>16010</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.namespace.init.timeout</name>
      <value>2400000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.port</name>
      <value>16000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.ui.readonly</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.master.wait.on.regionservers.timeout</name>
      <value>30000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.region.server.rpc.scheduler.factory.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.PhoenixRpcSchedulerFactory</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.executor.openregion.threads</name>
      <value>20</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size</name>
      <value>0.4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.hlog.blocksize</name>
      <value>134217728</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port</name>
      <value>16030</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.optionalcacheflushinterval</name>
      <value>7200000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
      <value>16020</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.rest.port</name>
      <value>8090</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
      <value>authentication</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
      <value>90000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.rs.cacheblocksonwrite</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
      <value>simple</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.shutdown.hook</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.superuser</name>
      <value>hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/tmp/hbase-${user.name}</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>zk01,zk2,zk3</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.useMulti</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hfile.block.cache.size</name>
      <value>0.40</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hfile.index.block.max.size</name>
      <value>131072</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>io.storefile.bloom.block.size</name>
      <value>131072</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>phoenix.query.timeoutMs</name>
      <value>60000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>zookeeper.recovery.retry</name>
      <value>6</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
      <value>120000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
      <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>

  </configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HDInsight-HbaseTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>HDInsight-HbaseTest</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>HDInsight-HbaseTest</name>
  <description>HDInsight-HbaseTest</description>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
     <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
     <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.4.0-HBase-1.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jdk.tools/jdk.tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_151</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

   <build>
    <!--  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
     <resources>
     <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>false</filtering>
         <includes>
         <include>hbase-site.xml</include>
         </includes>
     </resource>
     </resources>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.3</version>
         <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
         </plugin>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3</version>
         <configuration>
         <transformers>
             <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheLicenseResourceTransformer">
             </transformer>
         </transformers>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
             <goal>shade</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: may be you are missing some hdfs jars in your classpath

Comment: Thanks mbvxi for reply.. i have added the hadoop jars and working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving FQDN for zookeeper quorum?

Config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",
             "**zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181"**);